# Is it possible to restrict disabling gps, internet or enabling flight mode

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gps

I am developing a mobile application for tracking employee location in ionic.
The issues what I am facing is, users disabling gps / internet or enabling the flight mode. So it's very hard to track their respective location.

Now what I did is, if user turns-off gps/internet. I have created a log file, and send the log to server when he turns on again. I can't do anything specifically for disabling flight mode, so I check the internet/gps only.

Is my method is correct or Is any alternate thing that can be used to restrict disabling gps, internet or enabling flight mode. or it is possible only in native application.

Comment: I don't think it is possible unless the device is rooted, if you get this working, please share, very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should install your app as device owner. As device owner app you have full control of location, your app can enable it and disable it without user intervention. The problem with airplane mode still remains but you can just use a job service scheduling work with a constraint "network type any", when the connection come back, you can send the log file filled offline. Generally it's better to send more data together using a job compared to send a single location each time to avoid battery drain